# Query parameters are lost from POST request (nodeJS & Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying for the first time to make a JavaScript client and nodeJS server with Express communicate using REST API. For some reason, any parameter I give in `xhttp.send` is lost when arriving the back-end.

In the client side I have the following function:

```js
function changeStatus(station) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "/api", false);
  xhttp.send(`station=${station}`);
  window.location.reload();
}
```

And in the server side the following:

```js
app.post("/api", function (req, res) {
  if ("station" in req.query) {
    db[req.query.station] = !db[req.query.station];
    res.send(
      `Station ${req.query.station} changed to ${db[req.query.station]}`
    );
  } else {
    res.send("No station specified");
  }
});
```

In any case I get the 'else' configuration. Any suggestion on what to do? I also can't figure out how to log the raw request to attach.

Comment: have you checked `req.body` on your express server? For post requests it should be there

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, observe the POST request being made by this code.  Is there any value on the query string?  Or is that value somewhere else in the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query parameters aren't being lost. They don't exist. Query parameters go on the URL after a `?` after the path segment.

```
http://example.com?this=is&a=set&of=query&parameters=!
```

When you make a POST request, the value you pass to `send()` is sent in the request **body** which is accessible via `req.body` if (as per [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)) you have a suitable body-parsing middleware set up.

You should also set a `Content-Type` request header to tell the server how to parse the body you are sending it. `XMLHttpRequest` will do that automatically if you pass it a `URLSearchParams` object instead of a string.

---

Client-side code

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/api", false);
const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.append("station", station);
xhttp.send(body);
window.location.reload();
```

---

Server side code

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post("/api", function (req, res) {
    if ("station" in req.body) {
```

---

All that said, you are making an Ajax request and then immediately reloading the page.

The point of Ajax is to make requests *without* reloading the page.

You might as well use a regular `<form>` submission instead. It would be simpler.